# Changing values in a list with a tuple and a value

Tags: python, list, loops

I have the following issue:

```
my_list = [
  [(0.12064145946741212, 0.8105813193990855), 0.007220216606498195],
  [(0.12064145946741212, 0.8040496407576747), 0.007220216606498195]
]
```

I need to change the values inside the tuple if they negative to become 0 and for the value outside the tuple if is 0 to become 0.01.

How would i do this?Im lost

Comment: Iterate over the list, rewrite the tuple values if they meet your condition, check and change the value outside the tuple if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [
  [(0.12064145946741212, 0.8105813193990855), 0.007220216606498195],
  [(0.12064145946741212, 0.8040496407576747), 0.007220216606498195],
  [(-1, 0.8105813193990855), 0],
  [(0.12064145946741212, -1), 0.007220216606498195],
  [(-1, -1), 2],
  [(-1, -1), 0]]

[[(a[0], a[1]) if a[0]>0 and a[1]>0 else (0, 0) if a[0]<0 and a[1]<0 else (0, a[1]) if a[0]<0 else (a[0], 0)] + [0.01] if c==0 
 else [(a[0], a[1]) if a[0]>0 and a[1]>0 else (0, 0) if a[0]<0 and a[1]<0 else (0, a[1]) if a[0]<0 else (a[0], 0)] + [c] 
 for a, c in my_list]
```

output:

```
[[(0.12064145946741212, 0.8105813193990855), 0.007220216606498195],
 [(0.12064145946741212, 0.8040496407576747), 0.007220216606498195],
 [(0, 0.8105813193990855), 0.01],
 [(0.12064145946741212, 0), 0.007220216606498195],
 [(0, 0), 2],
 [(0, 0), 0.01]]
```

Comment: tks.. As a follow up how do i drop the whole list if the first value of the list is negative. i mean drop only one of the lists

Comment: @ Reblochon Masque , how would you turn this function into a list comprehension.. any tips on building list comprehensions.
    def boundaries(val, minval, maxval):
    if val < minval:
        return minval
    elif val > maxval:
        return maxval
    else:
        return val